# Uniform continuity on (0,1) implies boundedness

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, uniform-continuity

I need to prove that if $f: (0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is Uniformly continuous then it is  bounded.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you know about uniform continuous functions and continuous functions on compact sets?

Comment: I haven't studied yet about compact sets.

Comment: What do you know about continuous functions on closed bounded intervals? Can you extend $f$ continuously to $[0,1]$?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Recall that if $f$ is uniformly continuous, then given $\epsilon>0$ we can find $\delta>0$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$.

To show it is bounded, it doesn't really matter what $\epsilon$ is, so let it be some fixed constant.  Let $N=\lfloor\frac{1}{\delta}\rfloor$ and take
$$x_1=\delta,\  x_2=2\delta,\dots,\  x_n=n\delta,\dots, x_N=N\delta.$$  Notice every $y\in (0,1)$ satisfies $|y-x_i|<\delta$ for some $i$. Then $|f|$ will be bounded by $$\text{max}_{1\leq i\leq N} \{|f(x_i)|+\epsilon \}$$

which follows by applying the definition of Uniformly Continuous.

Hope that helps,

Comment: You're saying that you're walking on this range, in steps of 1/delta? can you clarify more this sentence Notice every y∈(0,1) satisfies |y−xi|<δ? Thank you so much.

Comment: @Nir:  Certainly.  Lets find explicitly which $x_i$ to take depending on $y$ (this may be better than the intuitive explanation, I am not sure).  Let $y\in(0,1)$.  Set $r=\lfloor\frac{y}{\delta}\rfloor$, and then we can write $y=r\delta + e$ where $e<\delta$ (this follows from what the floor function is).  Then as $x_r=\delta r$ we see $y-x_r=e$ and hence $|y-x_r|<\delta$

Comment: Why is $y\in (0,1)$ ?

Answer (score 7):

Here's one approach.  You can use uniform continuity (with $\varepsilon=1$, say) to show that $f$ is bounded on $(0,\delta)$ and $(1-\delta,1)$.  You probably already know the theorem that implies that $f$ is bounded on $[\delta,1-\delta]$.

If you don't know about boundedness of continuous functions on $[a,b]$, then what you can do here is cover $(0,1)$ with a finite number of tiny intervals where you know (using uniform continuity) that $f$ can't vary by more than $1$.

Uniformly continuous functions can also be extended to the closure, so an approach that would actually do more would be to show that $\lim_{x\to1}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$ exist, so that you may consider $f$ to be a restriction of a continuous function on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Hmm, that is what I said in the comments I guess. I did not really want to give the answer.

Comment: @Jonas T: You're right, the last paragraph in my answer has the same idea you gave in the comments.  There was no intentional overlap, just a delay in finishing the writing.  For just this problem, though, that approach would be slightly more work than the others I suggested.

Comment: Yes, you're right, but the idea is more general I think. If you have the theorem that you have a continuous extension and that a continuous function is bounded on a compact set it is a one line proof. But probably he didn't have the first one.

Comment: @Jonas T: Yes, and that is actually the way I thought of it initially.  To show that a uniformly continuous function $f$ on a totally bounded metric space is bounded, you can either cover the space with finitely many $\delta$ balls on which $f$ varies by no more than $1$, or you can argue that $f$ can be continuously extended to the completion, which is compact.  The first is more direct, but the second is how I tend to think of it.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $A$ is a bounded set such that $f(A)$ is unbounded. We can choose a sequence $(f(x_n))$ in $f(A)$ such that $|f(x_n)|>n$. Now $X=(x_n)$ is a bounded sequence and hence admits a convergent subsequence $Y=(x_{n_k})$. But $Y$ is a Cauchy sequence whose image under $f$ (a uniformly continuous function) is not Cauchy.