# Follow-up question: what if the interval is not (0, 1)? Say (1, 2)?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

Original post: [If $f(x)$ is continuous and bounded on $(0,1)$, is it uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87832/if-fx-is-continuous-and-bounded-on-0-1-is-it-uniformly-continuous-on)

I was just wondering if the result would be the same if one considered a different interval from (0, 1)? Say (1, 2)?

Thanks

Comment: It's the same outcome.

Comment: You can choose any bounded interval $(a,b)$. Just take the proof for $(0,1)$ and replace $0,1$ by $a,b$.

Comment: You just translate $f$ $a$ units to the right using $f(x-a)$.  This doesn't change the shape of curve.

Comment: Thanks for the replies