# Analysis - proof review please

Tags: real-analysis

Problem statement:

Prove that if $f$ is uniformly continuous on a bounded set $S$,
then $f$ is a bounded function on S.

Proof:

Assume $f$ is unbounded on $S$.

Take sequence $(x_n)$ from $S$ defined so that:

$f(x_2) > f(x_1) > 1$

$f(x_3) > f(x_2) > 2$

$...$

$f(x_{n+1}) > f(x_n) > n$

which is possible since $f$ is unbounded. By the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem, there exists a convergent subsequence of $(x_n)$; let it be $(x_{n_k})$ Since $(x_{n_k})$ is convergent, it is a Cauchy sequence. Since $f$ is uniformly continuous on $S$, $f(x_{n_k})$ must be a Cauchy sequence. However, since the sequence is clearly increasing and the function $f$ is unbounded, it cannot be convergent and thus cannot be a Cauchy sequence, which is a contradiction.

Therefore, $f$ is bounded on $S$.

My proof just feels a bit odd. Can someone point out logical holes, if any? Additionally, any proof writing tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: There is detail missing. Is $f$ a function between metric spaces?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the book I'm using at the moment has not mentioned metric spaces; f is a real valued function.

Comment: The set $S$ is assumed bounded (not closed). What allows you then to conclude that the subsequence $x_{n_{k}}$ is convergent to a point $x$ (the aim $f(x_{n_{k}})\rightarrow f(x)$ is otherwise good).

Comment: I'm not exactly sure. Is there any way to salvage the proof? As far as I understand Bolzano-Weierstrass, I thought that it implied exactly this.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88257/uniform-continuity-and-boundedness