# Cauchy sequence and uniform continuity

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity, cauchy-sequences

I read somewhere that because uniform continuous function maps Cauchy sequence to Cauchy sequence and Cauchy sequence is bounded, so the function must be bounded. I am not sure if it is correct. My concern is that what happens if the value that I am plugging into the function is not part of the Cauchy sequence, how can I be sure that it is bounded. Can someone verify whether this idea is correct? That uniform continuity imply boundedness using the fact that it maps Cauchy sequence to Cauchy sequence. Thanks

Comment: The sequence is bounded, not the function.

Comment: I've noticed that you have already asked more than 30 questions in April. I wanted to make sure that you are aware of the quotas 50 questions/30 days and 6 questions/24 hours, so that you can plan posting your questions accordingly. (If you try to post more questions, StackExchange software will not allow you to do so.) For more details see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4770/).

Comment: ok thanks my exam is coming next week, after that i will probably ask less questions.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given as $f(x)=x$ on $\mathbb{R}$.
It is clear that $f$ is uniform continuous but not bounded.

Comment: then is this wrong? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88257/uniform-continuity-and-boundedness

Comment: Your statement "uniform continuous function is bounded" is wrong and $f(x)=x$ is a counter example

Comment: have u read the link? what is it proving then?

Comment: @user136266 In the link you provided is the result saying: *Every uniformly continuous function $f\colon I\to\mathbb R$ is bounded.* Here $I$ denotes a **bounded interval**. In this case the above function is not a counterexample. (And, as far as I know, this result is correct.)

Comment: @Martin Sleziak what happens if i plug in a value that is not part of the cauchy sequence into the function, how can i be sure that the output from the function is within the bound of the cauchy sequence, the one that the function maps to?

Answer (score 0):

As you have already seen in another answer, a uniformly continuous function $f\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is not necessarily bounded.

But this is true:

> **Claim.** If $I\subseteq\mathbb R$ is a bounded interval and $f\colon I\to\mathbb R$ is a uniformly continuous, then $f$ is bounded.

Bounded intervals have several possible forms: $I=(a,b)$, $I=(a,b]$, $I=[a,b)$, $I=[a,b]$. But in any of these cases the closure $\overline I=[a,b]$ is a compact interval.

Let me try to give a proof of the above claim using the fact that $\overline I$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb R$ and your idea to use the fact that $f$ preserves Cauchy sequences.

*Proof.* Suppose that $f$ is unbounded. This means that there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ such that $x_n\in I$ and $|f(x_n)|\to\infty$.

Since $\overline I$ is compact, the sequence $(x_n)$ has a convergent subsequence $(x_{n_k})$. However, we only know that the limit of this subsequence belongs to $\overline I$. We do not know whether the limit belongs to $I$.

But even the fact that the subsequence $x_{n_k}$ is convergent in some larger space is sufficient to imply that this subsequence is Cauchy.

So we have a Cauchy sequence $(x_{n_k})$ such that the sequence $(f(x_{n_k}))$ is unbounded. Therefore $(f(x_{n_k}))$ is not Cauchy, a contradiction. $\hspace{2cm}\square$