# Uniform Continuity and Boundedness Proof

Tags: real-analysis

Does uniform continuity imply boundedness?

I know this question has been asked many times on this site. However, I found different answers from different people.

[Uniform continuity and boundedness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88257/uniform-continuity-and-boundedness)

This link seems to suggest that it does.

However, f(x) = x seems to be a counter example.

So which one is correct? Or is the link proving other things which I am not aware of.

Thanks

Comment: The hypothesis given in that link is "If $f$ is uniformly continuous on a *bounded* interval $I$". $f(x) = x$ is uniformly continuous and bounded on any bounded interval.

Comment: That's depende on the domain of your function. If you are considering a bounded interval obvious yes

Comment: This link seems to suggest that it does "when the domain of $f$ is a **bounded interval**." As long as you're considering $f:x\mapsto x$ on a bounded interval, it's bounded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f$ is uniformly continuous on a *bounded* set, then $f$ is bounded.

But if the domain of $f$ is not bounded, then $f$ may be not bounded too, as you have proved with the function $f(x)=x$.